# How to convert into json after fetching from AWS dynamoDB getItem() in python3.7 environment?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function which fetch item from DynamoDB by using getItem in Python3.7 environment. I am getting data correctly as shown below.
I want to convert {\"status\": 1,\n  \"number\": 12} string into JSON. Since I am new to python facing issues. I have tried dumps() and loads() but not working in my case. Any suggestions?

```
{
    "key": {
        "S": "{\"status\": 1,\n  \"number\": 12}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python ships with an inbuilt [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library, you can include it with

```
import json
```

`json` has a method called [loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) with loads a json string and converts it into a dict.

```
data = json.loads(response['key']['S'])
```